# Can't open uploaded image file with RMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, rmagick

In my Rails app, I have a form that allows users to upload images. My app is supposed to resize the images with the following controller method. (POST to this method, `params[:file]` contains the [`ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/UploadedFile.html) that was uploaded:

```
 def resize_and_store
    file = params[:file]

    # resize image
    Magick::Image.read(file.tempfile).first
    newimg = image.resize(100,100)

    #etc... Store newimg
  end
```

I get the following error, on the line that says `Image.read`:

```
Magick::ImageMagickError (no decode delegate for this image format `0xb9f6052c>' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544):
```

Testing this with an uploaded PNG file, it seems RMagick doesn't pick up that the temporary file is a PNG file. The code above *does* work if I read a locally stored PNG file, so it can't be that I'm missing the PNG decoder. How can I fix this and why does this happen?

Comment: Are you sure that's what's in `params[:file]`? I've only ever operated on the actual uploaded file, e.g., the model property.

Comment: And I believe you need to update question heading: change `Can` to `Can't` ;)

Comment: Oops! The debugger says the type is #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb8d46cb0> with a `image/png`  content type. Does this same code work for you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `from_blob` on a `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` param (this is how a file comes in):

```
images = Magick::Image.from_blob(params[:file].read)
```

Answer (score 3):

Storing the file temporarily will solve the problem:

```
open('temp.png', 'wb') do |file|
  file << uploaded.tempfile.read
end
images=Magick::Image.read('temp.png')
```

Probably wise to check input size as well.

Alternatively, parse the image from a blob.

Comment: I think this answer is even better than joost's answer and should get accepted 1+

Answer (score 2):

Using the answer by @joost (or similar approach) really helped to point me in the right direction but it didn't work on the second attempt with the same temp file - my use case was creating multiple image types from the tempfile source. This is what I've used, wrapping in a File.open block so we don't leak the file descriptor:

```
File.open(tempfile, "rb") do |f|
  img = Magick::Image::from_blob(f.read).first
  resized = img.resize_to_fit(w, h)
  resized.write(dest)
  resized.destroy!
  img.destroy!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's something wrong with the form? You can consult with Rails Guide here:

[Rails Guides: Uploading Files](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files)

I think that you may have `multipart: true` missing in your form declaration.
Also, I would strongly advise to use [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to handle file uploads. Among several things, it will help you to organize your file transformations (putting logic out of the controllers). Here's a railscast about it:

[RailsCasts: CarrierWave File Uploads](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads).

Good luck!

Comment: The form is fine... I can store the image to disk, etc, RMagick just can't handle temporary files!